# Update connection string on ASP.NET MVC (Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I use database first Entity Framework context model.

My question is this: **how can I update the application if the current databse has been moved to another server**?

- Same database name
- Same username & password

I've actually managed to connect to the new server from SQL Management studio with the same credentials, but the application doesn't connect.

**What I have tried to do:**

I changed the server name in the connection string (left other values as they are).

Is there a standard way to perform such change?

**UPDATE**

Should I execute `Update model from database` to the .edmx file?

Comment: What you've done (change the server name) should work. Where are you storing the connection string? Can you post the relevant section of code/configuration?

Comment: the .config file should have the connectionstring, can you check

Comment: I am opening Web.config to change the connection string

Comment: It is possible there is a firewall blocking the connection from your application to your database. Assuming your database is running on the default port of `1433`, log into the web server via remote desktop and run `telnet *servernameOrIP* 1433`. If it connects then this isn't the issue. If it times out, you need to ensure port `1433` is allowed through any firewalls that may be between the 2 servers. It is also possible that the server name is not resolving - you might try the IP address instead of the name to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your change should work in a normal scenario. However, can you check if there is any service account that is associated with the New Database in the SQL Server. If that is the case, then you need to set the Identity property of the Application pool that your MVC application is configured to use.

1. Go to IIS,
2. Select Application Pools
3. Select the application pool (e.g. DefaultAppPool)
4. Select 'Advanced Settings'
5. Set the Identity property with the correct username and password (if any).

Answer (score 0):

copy & paste connection string to web config file from Your Database provider with Your credentials.

Make sure that Your db context class contains exact same name as Your DB.

(if it's necessary)-allow Your IP address to access to DB in Your Db provider management panel.
if there any other problems show us Your error message.